# Check for next available row in a column

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

So say I've got a 2D array like:

```
[
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 2],
    [0, 2, 2, 0, 2],
    [1, 1, 2, 1, 1],
]
```

And I want the two players (player 1 is represented by 1 and player 2 is represented by 2) to be able to place counters down the columns (like connect 4). How can I find the next available row (if there are any)?

I can parse the column number

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
table = [                                                                           
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],                                                                
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],                                                                
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 2],                                                                                                                
    [0, 2, 2, 0, 2],                                                                                                                
    [1, 1, 2, 1, 1],                                                                                                                
]                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
def move(col, player, table):                                                   
    available_rows = [i for i in range(len(table)) if table[i][col]==0]         
    if available_rows == []:                                                    
        return False # i.e. you can not place on column col. invalid move                     
    target_row = available_rows[-1]  # target_row is the next available move on column col                                           
    table[target_row][col] = player                                             
    return True # i.e. valid move                                                                
                                                                                
print(table)                                                                    
move(0, 2, table)  # player 2 has placed its move on column 0 (zero based index)                                                             
print(table)
```

Output

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 2], 
 [0, 2, 2, 0, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 1, 1]
]

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 2],
 [1, 2, 2, 0, 2],
 [1, 1, 2, 1, 1]]
```

You have to check whether the output of move is true or not, to make sure the move is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to loop through the array, and check if the current row has any zero in it.

```py
for row in array:
   if row.count(0) > 0:
      # this row has available slots
      # Do something here
      break
else:
   # No free slot at all for all rows
   # Do something here
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution:

```
def findNextRow(self, rowNumber):
    for rowIndex in range(len(self._grid), 0, -1):
        if self._grid[rowNumber][rowIndex] == 0:
            return rowIndex-1
    return False
```

You loop backwards through the 2d array. If the column number you parsed through and the current row is 0, then return the index-1 (since python array indexing starts at 0). If no row can be found, the loop will end without returning anything so you can return False.